# Does sharing a DTO class between methods create vulnerabilities regarding 'extra' properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, dto

I'm creating a API where I have two methods. The first one is a Register method:

```
[HttpPost("register")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Register(UserDto request)
{
  // User validation
}
```

The second is a Login method:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> Login(UserDto request)
{
  // User validation
}
```

Here is my DTO class:

```
public class UserDto
    {
        public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty; 
        public string Lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
```

The main problem is that I need different attributes for each method. In the **REGISTRATION** method, I need all the fields: Username, Password, Name, LastName, PhoneNumber). Whereas in the **LOGIN** method I just need the Username & Password fields.

I'm concerned about system vulnerabilities by using the same DTO class between methods (which works, but might expose extra fields that aren't needed). Do I need to create another DTO class with just the fields I need for each method? Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes, this is a great practice. Your model should be called `UserRegistration` and only be used in one-way POST. You `User` model should not contain `Password`. If user changes password, you might need a third model, or not even a model. Send user a link which will open a page.

Comment: Why are you worried about creating different DTOs? I guess there are reasons for both sides - but TMHO - it is better to seperate DTOs based on its usage. In that manner you will be able to modify the different DTOs without worrying how it might affect the others. I think it is related to tight-coupling, which better be avoided

Comment: Even if separate requests happen to have the same parameters but they are logically distinct - it's better to have separate request objects. For example, you have two requests which accept id and one returns person, while the other returns Payment. You could get away with some "IdRequest" object for both of them (since they both need the same Id parameter and nothing else), but it's much better to have separate PersonRequest and PaymentRequest. And in your situation there is no doubt - just use different objects (I would not call them DTO in this case by the way).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach you could use is to move the common properties to a base class, and inherit the base class wherever you need it. for an instance, you could move UserName and Password to a base class.

```
public class UserBaseDto
{
   public string Username { get; set; } = string.Empty;
   public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}


public class UserDto : UserBaseDto
{
   public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty; 
   public string Lastname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
   public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

But it’s best to avoid using inheritance in DTOs unless absolutely necessary. If you do need to use inheritance, try to keep the base class as simple as possible so that any changes won’t have too much of an impact on the derived classes